# Does heat flow through a rod with a uniform current?

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider a rod with uniform current flowing through it from left to right.

Will heat flow throughout the rod or will the rod heat up uniformly?

My thoughts are that no heat will flow, but rather the rod will heat up uniformly per unit volume. My reasoning is that, if the current is uniform, then there is no reason why heat will be produced more at one point on the rod than another, thus resulting in no heat gradient.

Can someone please clarify?

Comment: If the rod is surrounded by perfect insulation, then I think that you're correct in saying that the rod will heat up uniformly and that no heat will flow. For a real situation, though, heat will be lost at the surfaces of the rod, and so heat will flow from the center of the rod outward and there will also be a temperature gradient. Don't understand your last paragraph about infinitesimal segments, though. Suggest clarifying that paragraph.

Comment: Your analysis is correct.

Comment: I just deleted it, it doesn't help the question.

Comment: OK, so physically my analysis is correct. However, there is an expression that goes like $H+\kappa\frac{d^2T}{dx^2}=\rho C\frac{dT}{dt}$ where T is the temperature. Would this not then imply that heat does flow since there is a change in $x$ for a change in $T$?

Comment: You can solve the heat equation with a convection term to see for sure what is going on.

Comment: @ODP - The equation you wrote down does not imply that there has to be a temperature gradient. In the case of the rod surrounded by perfect insulation, I believe that the solution would be that the temperature gradient is zero throughout the rod, so the 2nd derivative of the temperature with respect to position would be zero. The resulting equation would describe a situation where there is no heat flow and all of the generated heat goes into raising the temperature of each volume element of the wire rod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a trick question.   If the rod is constantan, and the current
enters on the left on a copper wire, and drains on the right into a copper
wire, the circuit is a type T thermocouple.  The Peltier effect will chill one end of the rod, heat the other, and the resulting thermal imbalance will cause end-to-end heat flow inside the rod.   While this sounds kinda tricky, it is actually an important effect (and some aspects of precision electronic design require good thermal practices).   If, however, there are no materials-choice tricks intended, the rod will heat uniformly (attaining a temperature distribution according to any surface cooling which may occur).

Ohm's law at a point:  dV/dx = j * rho       volts/m

Heat flux at a point:  dW/dv = j^2 * rho     watts/m^3

Comment: Thanks, this is a really insightful answer. I know that in the case I am wondering about heat does in fact flow, the reason being that the question says that heat flows. I doubted the validity of this, but thank you for the answer.